# VimのmapleaderにMacのCommandを割り当てたい

Tags: vim

現状、私はVimのmapleaderに<\Space>を割り当てているのですが、挿入モードになった時に初動がもたつくのでCommandキーに変更しようと思っています。
その場合mapleaderにはどのような値を入れれば良いのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

現在
`let mapleader = "\<Space>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command キー単独での登録はできないと思われます。これは Command に限ったことではなく Ctrl や Alt でも同様です。

他のキーとの組み合わせはできる可能性があります。 <kbd>c</kbd> との組み合わせであれば以下のように設定してみてください。

```
let mapleader = "\<D-c>"
```

また [`:help mac`](http://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/os_mac.html) も合わせて参照してください。